# Execution timeout strategy for a Java method

Tags: java

I have a system which services a large amount of transactions. 
The timeout strategy applies for only a part of a transaction.

A complete transaction here consists of some execution workflow, pre-processing, a remote call, post-processing etc..

For example,

> // some code
>
> // START TIMER
>
> try
>   {
>
> > CallInput remoteInput = fInputProcessor.transform(callContext);
> >
> > CallOutput remoteOutput = fRemoteInvoker.invoke(remoteInput);
> >
> > TransactionOutput  output = fOutputProcessor.transform(remoteOutput);
>
> }
>
> catch(TimeoutException ex)
>   {
>
> }
>
> // some code

Say the timeout is for 500ms. It may occur during the Input processing, the remote call or the output processing.

Can you list some possible ways of generating the Timeout after 500ms? Assume I cannot split the 3 blocks into a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `java.util.concurrent.Future.get(long, TimeUnit)`.

```
Runnable yourTask = <wrap your work code in a Runnable>;
Future future = threadpool.submit(yourTask);
try {
    Object result = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (Exception e) {
    <handle exception, e.g. TimeoutException>
} finally {
    <your closing code>
}
```

Here is an example to create/destroy a threadpool :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

private ExecutorService threadpool;

public void start() {
    threadpool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}

public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
    threadpool.shutdown();
    if (false == threadpool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        threadpool.shutdownNow();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and use this such code:

```
TimeLimiter limiter = new SimpleTimeLimiter();
limiter.callWithTimeout(new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() {
          CallInput remoteInput = fInputProcessor.transform(callContext);
          CallOutput remoteOutput = fRemoteInvoker.invoke(remoteInput);
          TransactionOutput output = fOutputProcessor.transform(remoteOutput);
    }
  }, 500, TimeUnit.MILISECONDS, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

DelayQueues (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) are also useful. You add elements to the queue that implements the Delayed interface, which is used to define the expiration for the Delayed object. Then you can poll the queue for elements that have expired and do something with them

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     doSomethingWithExpiredObj();
}
```